# c# selenium whatsapp Web

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am writing automation in c# to send messages, photos and pdfs to the number entered when the button is pressed,
I enter the textbox phone number and press the button, the site opens, but chrome sends an alert if you want to open whatsapp's application, I want to press the cancel button, but no matter what I do, I need your help, thanks

//IAlert alert = driver.SwitchTo().Alert();
//alert.Dismiss();
doesn't work

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;

.
.
.

   public void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       string telefonNumarasi = maskedTextBox1.Text;

       telefonNumarasi = telefonNumarasi.Replace("(", "").Replace(")", "").Replace(" ", "").Replace("-", "");

       string temizTelefonNumarasi = telefonNumarasi;
       label1.Text = temizTelefonNumarasi;


       BASE_URL2 = "https://api.whatsapp.com/send/?phone=90" + temizTelefonNumarasi + "&text&type=phone_number&app_absent=0";
       IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
       driver.Url = BASE_URL2;
       driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(BASE_URL2);
       driver.WaitForPageLoad();
       try
       {


           //IAlert alert = driver.SwitchTo().Alert();
           //alert.Dismiss();
           IWebElement sohbeteBasla = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id=\"action-button\"]"));
           sohbeteBasla.Click();



       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {

           MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

       }

   }
   public static string BASE_URL2 { get; set; } = "https://api.whatsapp.com/send/?phone=" +123 + "&text&type=phone_number&app_absent=0";
```

Comment: [Selenium Alert & Popup Window Handling: How to Handle](https://www.guru99.com/alert-popup-handling-selenium.html)